# Terminate subprocess in python doesn't work

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, terminate, kill-process

I want to terminate a subprocess, but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
import os
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal','-e','tshark -i eth0 -w /root/Desktop/test.pcap'])
q = subprocess.Popen(['python','avtp2.py'])

if q.wait() == 0:
  p.terminate()
```

Do you know why?

Greetz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_output
import signal

p = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal','-e','tshark -i eth0 -w /root/Desktop/test.pcap'],shell=False)
q = subprocess.Popen(['python','avtp2.py'])

if q.wait() == 0:
  p_pid = check_output(["pidof","tshark"]).split()
  os.kill(int(p_pid[0]), signal.SIGINT)
```

Comment: why not use  ```p_pid = p.pid```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> `Popen.wait()`
>
> Wait for child process to terminate. Set and return returncode attribute.

So for the body of the if to run, the process has to first terminate, you can use `q.poll()` instead, since it doesn't blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Francisco Couzo, but I found a solution myself just now :D